# R facet labels with expressions using label_parsed

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet

I'm trying to put expressions into facet labels using label_parsed but with no success:

```
library(ggplot2)
mpg3 <- mpg
levels(mpg3$drv)[levels(mpg3$drv)=="4"] <- "4^{wd}"
levels(mpg3$drv)[levels(mpg3$drv)=="f"] <- "- Front %.% e^{pi * i}"
levels(mpg3$drv)[levels(mpg3$drv)=="r"] <- "4^{wd} - Front"


ggplot(mpg3, aes(x=displ, y=hwy)) + geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ drv, labeller = label_parsed)
```

The [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtWbU.jpg) that I get lacks expressions - facet labels contain the original levels of drv variable.

If I type `levels(mpg3$drv)` I get `character(0)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems - firstly `mpg$drv` is character, not factor, and secondly, you need to set the factor labels, not the levels.  I think this is what you want...

```
mpg3 <- mpg
mpg3$drv <- factor(mpg3$drv,
                   levels=c("4","f","r"),
                   labels=c("4^{wd}","- Front %.% e^{pi * i}","4^{wd} - Front"))

ggplot(mpg3, aes(x=displ, y=hwy)) + 
      geom_point() +
      facet_grid(. ~ drv, labeller = label_parsed)
```

[image]